# Refactor javascript to avoid apostrophes causing issues?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, string, apostrophe

I have taken over a website and there is a lot of javascript that looks like this;

```
 function BuildHTMLString(item)
 {  
       return "<input name='Text' Type='text' value='" + item+ "' />";
 }
```

these strings are then being used in posting forms.  I realized that if the variable item has an apostrophe in it, this whole thing breaks down.

What is a recommended way to programatically populate textboxes that will be part of a form post that doesn't create an issue with names with apostrophe in it.

Comment: What about creating actual elements instead of using strings?

Comment: That code wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: @Dave Newton - can you clarify??

Comment: @leora You edited it; obviously it's okay now. In any case, you'd need to either JS-escape any strings you're embedding like that.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) to create elements programmatically and then use the [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML) property:

```
function buildHtmlString(item) {
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    element.setAttribute("name", "Text");
    element.setAttribute("type", "text");
    element.setAttribute("value", item);

    return element.outerHTML;
}
```

On Chrome, `buildHtmlString("this has a quote \"");` gives me:

```
<input name="Text" type="text" value="this has a quote &quot;">
```

I noticed that you added the `jquery` tag. So you can do this pretty easily with jQuery as well:

```
function buildHtmlString(item) {
    return jQuery("<input>").attr("name", "Text")
                            .attr("type", "text")
                            .attr("value", item)
                            .get(0).outerHTML;
}
```

Comment: is one of your point that i should change my single quotes to \"?

Comment: @leora Oh, no. It should work either way. If you invoke this with a single quote, it won't get escaped. Instead the generated HTML will use double quotes which removes the need for any single quotes to be escaped. Double quotes will be escaped as `&quot;` however.

Comment: I tried this approach but i am running into an issue, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24663029/jquery-dynamically-adding-textbox-encoding

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jQuery you can use it to create your elements:

```
var $input = $('<input>')
    .attr('name', 'Text')
    .attr('type', 'text')
    .attr('value', item);
```

Now you have an object that can be inserted on DOM or further manipulated.

If you want the HTML for anything other than inserting in the DOM, you can use `$input.get(0).outerHTML` to get it.

Comment: while i agree this is nicer than building up a string. how does this deal with the apostrophe issue.  What if the item variable has the word "doesn't" or something with an apostrophe

Comment: It work pretty good, as I'm just passing the variable as it is to jQuery. It handles that. In my test you get this result: `<input name="Text" type="text" value="don't">`

Comment: Why the minus vote? The questions tags denotes it uses jQuery and the answer is correct?

Comment: +1. Notice that this can be simplified to `$('<input>', {'name':'Text', 'type':'text', 'value':item})`